# CodeIgniter "status":false,"error":"Unknown method"

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter

I'm trying to create a REST service with codeigniter. I have installed RestController.

In my controller (Person):

```
    public function createUser(){
                $user = array(
                'fiscalcode' => $this->input->post('fiscalcode'),
                'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'surname' => $this->input->post('surname'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'));
                $data = $this->person_model->post_user($user);
                $this->response($data);
    }
```

While in my model (Person_model)

```
public function post_user($user){
            $this->fiscalcode = $user['fiscalcode'];
            $this->name = $user['name'];
            $this->surname = $user['surname'];
            $this->email = $user['email'];
if($this->db->insert('Persons', $this)){
                return 'Utente registrato';
            }
}
```

I have tried to use Postman to try if the insert works, I pass values in the body  form-data and I receive this error:

> {"status":false,"error":"Unknown method"}

In postman I have done a post to `index.php/Person/createUser`

Can you explain where is the error?

Comment: Please add post method from postman, RestController uses json,xml etc formats but you are trying to post form data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In codeigniter REST controller there is a naming convention when creating get or post methods. Use `_post` post-fix with method name for post and `_get` for get method, and use `$this->post('keyname')` to get the post data.

**POST Method**

```
public function createUser_post(){
            $user = array(
            'fiscalcode' => $this->post('fiscalcode'),
            'name' => $this->post('name'),
            'surname' => $this->post('surname'),
            'email' => $this->post('email'));
            $data = $this->person_model->post_user($user);
            $this->response($data, 200);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
public function post_user($user){
    if($this->db->insert('Persons', $user)) {
           return 'Utente registrato';
    }
}
```

Instead of

```
public function post_user($user){
            $this->fiscalcode = $user['fiscalcode'];
            $this->name = $user['name'];
            $this->surname = $user['surname'];
            $this->email = $user['email'];
if($this->db->insert('Persons', $this)){
                return 'Utente registrato';
            }
}
```

`$this->db->insert('Persons', $this)`, `$this` variable not only contain fiscalcode,name,email. but its also contain the method, and its not an array

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have changed as you wrote, but I receive the same error